# Button Event Handler updating Textfield issue

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, java-8, javafx-8

I'm receiving an error in the console that reads "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.StackOverflowError". This error is when I use a negative number; I know it's in this if/else statement as nothing was producing an error until I tried to update the textfields back to empty.

The error seems to point at my return lines of the factorial method, this only happens when I set the textfields back to spaces after the button is re-clicked.

EDIT: I forgot to state that the program compiles and will reset the fields correctly, it just throws this error into the console while doing so. How can I fix this?

```
butCalcFact.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            String inputText = tfInput.getText();

            if (Integer.parseInt(inputText) < 0) {
                tfError.setText("Error: Invalid number entered.");
                tfResult.setText("    ");
                System.out.println("Error: Invalid number entered.");
            } else
                tfError.setText(" ");
                tfResult.setText(factorial(Integer.parseInt(inputText)) + "");

        }
    });

public static long factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0) // Base case
        return 1;
    else
        return n * factorial(n - 1); // Recursive call
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing brackets?

Next code calls for any input text:

```
tfResult.setText(factorial(Integer.parseInt(inputText)) + "");
```

And method `factorial` doesn't handle negative values properly.

Comment: The method is meant to be called when the number is 0 or greater, hence why I put it in the else statement. When the number is a negative doesn't it not get called?

Comment: Whoops never mind I saw the missing bracket, thank you!